# How to get Bus and Device relationship for a /dev/ttyUSB

Tags: server, usb, usb-modem, udev

I need to write an script for restart USB dongles. I have all tools but I can't link my /dev/ttyUSBx to physical BUS and DEVICE. An issue is that I have three dongles with the same id vendor and id product.

If I do lsusb the output is:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E270 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E270 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E270 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And I have attached it to:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0
/dev/ttyUSB3
/dev/ttyUSB5
```

But I want to know which device is related with which Bus Device. By example I need to get the following:

```
/dev/ttyUSB0 -> Bus 001 Device 006
/dev/ttyUSB3 -> Bus 001 Device 004
/dev/ttyUSB5 -> Bus 001 Device 007
```

I'm using Ubuntu Server 10.04 and I tested the tools:

```
lsusb
hal
lsmod
```

But I can't get the relationship.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since I don't have your hardware I can't give you an exact answer.

I'd suggest that you go to the device in question, for example:

```
ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and obtain the major and minor node numbers. Let's say they are 116, 7

Then go to:

```
ls -l /sys/dev/char/116:7
```

(`char`, because a tty is a character device, if you were tracing down a disk device you would specify `block` instead of `char`)

In the output from the command you will see something a little like:

`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sep  6 00:17 116:7 -> ../../devices//sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.5/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.5/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.1/sound/card1/pcmC1D0c`

The directory `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.5/usb1/1-3/` and its subdirectories have much information on the device. As an example, `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.5/usb1/1-3/busnum` and `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.5/usb1/1-3/devnum`. On my system these match the bus and device number mentioned in the device hotplug entries in /var/log/syslog.

Something else that works on my system for /dev/video0:

```
find /sys/dev -lname '*video0' -exec cat {}/device/busnum {}/device/devnum \; 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you very much!, I have fighting with this for many time. Just for further visitors: In my ubuntu Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS the device directory is /sys/dev/char/ instead of /sys/char/

Comment: Thanks for the correction--I've edited the answer with that change, and added a find command to print the information.

Comment: @JohnSGruber Ok, but how to mount it?!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde: You can't mount a /dev/ttyUSB; only some device that operates like a disk drive can be mounted.

Answer (score 12):

There really isn't a *good* way to map character devices like `/dev/ttyUSB0` to the corresponding USB device and bus numbers.  **BUT, it is possible!**

Something like this might work:

`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk`

From there, you'll get a bunch of information about the device and its parent devices.  Now, it's just all about parsing those data to get what you want.  I've used this in the past:

```
echo /dev/bus/usb/`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk | sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\4/p' | head -n 2 | awk '{$1 = sprintf("%03d", $1); print}'` | tr " " "/"
```

Now, if that's not a mouthful, I dunno what is!  Let's break it down:

**`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk`** - returns info about the device and its parent devices

**`sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\4/p'`** - parses these data and returns any lines containing the "devnum" or "busnum" attribute.  We'll assume that "busnum" is listed first... and in that case... we can just grab the first two lines of output.

**`head -n 2`** - Grab the first 2 lines of output.  We could get more fancy here, but we are just making an assumption that the closest parent's "busnum" and "devnum" are going to be listed first.

**`awk '{$1 = sprintf("%03d", $1); print}'`**  - Takes those digits and pads them with zeros.

**`echo /dev/bus/usb`...** - all this jazz is wrapped up into an `echo` statement to replace the newlines with spaces.  You can add the `-n` to `echo` if you want to cut off the trailing newline.

**`tr " " "/"`** - replace the spaces in the output with forward slashes

This will output something like:

```
/dev/bus/usb/001/011
```

... which, of course, is the device.  If you'd like, you can easily output something like `busnum:001 devnum:011` with a few tweaks:

```
echo `udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk | sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\1\ \4/p' | head -n 2 | awk '{$1 = sprintf("%s:%03d", $1, $2); print $1;}'`
```

Answer (score 2):

You are able to find many information about node using below command:

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/<specific tty>/
```

for example

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/ttyUSB0/
```

last slash is optional

If not having a component, you will see "syspath not found"

In many cases, this command brought same information with `udevadm info --name=/dev/<specific tty> --attribute-walk`

Comment: Please remove the trailing slash. It gives "syspath not found".