# Python syntax error with awk, sprintf statment (2.7)

Tags: sed, python-2.7, awk, syntax

I am trying to use one of the shell commands to a python script, but struggling with some syntax error here.

The description of the command is [from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184526/how-to-get-bus-and-device-relationship-for-a-dev-ttyusb/420584#420584?newreg=6a48100adea14f0c9a7e07819908eaef)

```
echo /dev/bus/usb/`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk | sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\4/p' | head -n 2 | awk '{$1 = sprintf("%03d", $1); print}'` | tr " " "/"
```

This command works well on the terminal, but trying to import this a python script

```
import subprocess
cmd = "/dev/bus/usb/`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk | sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\4/p' | head -n 2 | awk '{$1 = sprintf("%03d", $1); print}'` | tr " " "/""
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
print err
```

Get a syntax error on a sprintf statement, which doesn't explain much or doesn't like modulo (%)

Answer (score 2):

- You can't use " within "'s. Your command split into parts

  ```
  cmd = "
  /dev/bus/usb/`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk 
  | sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\4/p' 
  | head -n 2 
  | awk '{$1 = sprintf("%03d", $1); print}'` 
  | tr " " "/"
  "
  ```

The " on line 1 and line 7 interfere with the " on lines 5 and 6. You need to escape those. Line 3 escapes them correctly.

See the [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) section.

- Untested, but you probably need to do it like this:

  ```
  cmd = "
  /dev/bus/usb/`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk 
  | sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\4/p' 
  | head -n 2 
  | awk '{$1 = sprintf(\"%03d\", $1); print}'` 
  | tr \" \" \"/\"
  "
  ```

Maybe this works too:

```
cmd = "/dev/bus/usb/`udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyUSB0 --attribute-walk | sed -n 's/\s*ATTRS{\(\(devnum\)\|\(busnum\)\)}==\"\([^\"]\+\)\"/\4/p' | head -n 2 | awk '{$1 = sprintf('%03d', $1); print}'` | tr ' ' '/'"
```

I changed " into '.